# Aligning part of a div's content to bottom in a jQuery dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've created a portfolio page for myself and have run into the problem of wanting to align a link to the bottom of a div, which only shows if you click an arrow. I took pictures of the two states of the dropdown, they are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tE9Dq.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xd6p6.png). My goal is to align the "View on GitHub" link to the bottom, I've tried most of the things I found being suggested, but most of them either use display:table-cell, which breaks up the opening-closing animation, or they suggest relative and absolute positioning, which doesn't work with my current way of implementing the movement. If anyone has an idea, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Absolute and relative positioning does the positioning part correctly, but it's not following the expansion animation, which is what I'm looking for.

Here is the markup, the styling and the scripts that go with the relevant section:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".slidebtn").click(function() {

    $(this).parent(".projects-arrow").prev(".slider").slideToggle(1000);
    $(this).children().toggleClass("fa-angle-double-up fa-angle-double-down");
  });

});
```

```css
.projects-arrow {
  text-align: center;
}

#projects .summary {
  font-style: italic;
  height: 70px;
}

#projects .card .card-block {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: justify;
}

#projects .slider {
  height: 300px;
}

#projects .slider ul {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card col-md-5">
  <h4 class="card-header">My portfolio</h4>
  <div class="card-block summary">
    My portfolio page
  </div>
  <div class="card-block slider">
    <ul>
      <li>Used Materialize CSS and Bootstrap for the Front-end</li>
      <li>Back-end uses jQuery for few scripts</li>
      <li>Utilizes dynamic CSS properties as an effort to optimize it for multiple screen sizes</li>
      <li>Hosted on GitHub pages</li>

    </ul>
    <div class="projects-link">
      <a href="https://github.com/vghgergely/vghgergely.github.io" target="_blank"><strong>View on GitHub</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="projects-arrow">
    <a class="slidebtn"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What is the issue in setting position: relative to 'body' tag and absolute position the link with respect to this?

Comment: I've tried it just now and the positioning is correct, not sure what I messed up when I tried it before. The only thing is that the link appears as I click the button, not expanding with the div, which I would prefer. I can make a quick video if something is not clear.

Comment: Didn't get the issue. Can you make it work in code pen or something?

Comment: https://codepen.io/vghgergely/pen/aEwazj Here is the codepen! If you click the button you can see that the link doesn't disappear alongside the list, it disappears after everything is collapsed. Hope it's clearer now!